# JPQL Query for Java EE Project

Tags: sql, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, jpql

I am a beginner in JPQL queries and I don't understand how can I translate an SQL query in a JPQL query:

I have 2 tables:

- Customer(**idCustomer**,...,*idMacroMarket*)
- MacroMarket(**idMacroMarket**,*nameMacroMarket*...)

These tables are linked with a relation @ManytoOne (for Customer) and
@OneToMany (for MacroMarket).

**SQL query:**

```
SELECT nameMacroSegment FROM Macro_market m
INNER JOIN Customer c ON c.idMacroMarket = m.idMacroMarket
WHERE idCustomer = id;
```

**JPQL query:**

```
SELECT nameMacroSegment FROM Macro_market m
...
...
WHERE idCustomer = :id
```

**Entities**

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name="macro_market")
    public class Macro_market implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /** ATTRIBUTES **/

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long idMacroMarket;

        private String nameMacroSegment;
        private String nameMarketSegment;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="macMar")
        private List<Customer> customers;
        ...
        ...

    @Entity
    @Table(name="customer")
    public class Customer implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long idCustomer;

        ...     
        ...
        /** RELATIONS **/
        // CUSTOMER - MACRO_MARKET
        @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="idMacroMarket",referencedColumnName="idMacroMarket")
        private Macro_market macMar;
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: This may work:
    SELECT m.nameMacroSegment FROM Macro_market m, m.customers c
    WHERE c.idCustomer = :id

Comment: @kostja : Ok for the request, but now, I have this error :  m.customers is not mapped [SELECT m.nameMacroSegment FROM com.CustomerRequirement.entities.Macro_market m, m.customers c WHERE c.idCustomer = :id]

Comment: I just guessed what your mapping may look like. I assumed that since `MakroMarket` has a `OneToMany` relation to the `Customer`, it may be called `customers`. You should use whatever the actual name of the field is. PS - it would help if you posted the code for the two entities - only the relevant parts - class declaration, members, annotations, no methods, no comments.

Comment: @kostja : Yes, I have an attribute called customers in my Macro_market entity. This is a List<Customer> type. But it seems to be null. How can I fill in this List and When? Thank you Kostja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some deliberation, I think this query should work. In the query I wrote in the comments, I have missed the `JOIN` statement.

```
SELECT m.nameMacroSegment FROM Macro_market m JOIN m.customers
WHERE c.idCustomer = :id
```

As to the question when and how you can add new customers to the list - if you have a `MakroMarket` entity `market` and a `Customer` `customer` you can add them to the both sides of the relation like this:

```
market.getCustomers().add(customer);
customer.setMarket(market);
customer = entityManager.merge(customer); //save the changes to both entites with cascade
```

If you have created a new `Customer` you will also have to persist it instead of merging, using `em.persist(customer);`.

I hope this answers your question.